# chrome.storage.sync vs chrome.storage.local

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I was trying to understand how to use the chrome.storage.api.
I have included the following in my `manifest.json`:

```
"permissions": [
"activeTab","storage"
],
```

Than, I opened a new tab with the devtools and switched the `<page context>` to the one of my chrome-extension. Than I typed:

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({"foo":"bar"},function(){ console.log("saved ok"); } );
```

and got:

```
undefined
saved ok
```

Than I tried getting this stored value:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get("foo",function(data){ console.log(data); } );
```

but this got me:

```
undefined
Object {}
```

Than I did the same, but instead of `sync` I used `local` and this worked as expected:

```
chrome.storage.local.set({"foo":"bar"},function(){ console.log("saved ok"); } );
```

..and the retrieval:

```
chrome.storage.local.get("foo",function(data){ console.log(data); } );
```

Which got me: `Object {foo: "bar"}` as it should.

Is this because I am not signed in to my account on chrome? But in that case, isn't `chrome.storage.sync` designed to fallback into storing the data locally?

**EDIT**

Strangely, when i type this straight on console it seems to be working, but this code doesn't run from background.js code inside a click listener:

```
var dataCache = {};

function addStarredPost(post)
{
  var id = getPostId(post);
  var timeStamp = new Date().getTime();
  var user = getUserName();

  dataCache[id] = {"id":id,"post":post,"time":timeStamp,"user":user};
  chrome.storage.sync.set(dataCache,function(){ console.log("Starred!");});
}
```

After this is ran, `chrome.storage.sync.get(null,function(data){ console.log(data); });` returns an empty object as if the data wasn't stored. :/
This code seems to be working perfect with `chrome.storage.local` instead.

`chrome.runtime.lastErros` returns `undefined`

Comment: In a completely fresh profile, your `.get()` call returns `Object {foo: "bar"}`, which is what I expect. Can you double-check? You should ask your other question in another question.

Comment: @user1555863 try to call `chrome.runtime.lastError` to see the problem

Comment: @Intuitisoft `chrome.runtime.lastError` returns `undefined`. see edit.

Comment: change the title, this is not a chrome.storage.local vs chrome.storage.sync question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whoops!

The problem was I was trying to sync data that exceeded in size. (4096 Bytes per item)

I wasn't getting `chrome.runtime.lastError` because I was mistakenly putting it inside the `get` function scope, instead of the `set` function which was producing the error. Hence, I'm posting this answer so it might help others who share the same confusion.

You should check `chrome.runtime.lastError` inside each api call, like so:

```
chrome.storage.local.set(objectToStore, function(data)
{
   if(chrome.runtime.lastError)
   {
       /* error */
       console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
       return;
   }
  //all good. do your thing..
}
```

This ran OK with `chrome.storage.local` because [according to the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) you only have this limitation with `sync`.

printing `chrome.runtime.lastError` gave me: `Object {message: "QUOTA_BYTES_PER_ITEM quota exceeded"}`

Answer (score 20):

The max size for chrome local storage is 5,242,880 bytes.
To extend the storage you can add on the manifest.json :

```
"permissions": [
  "unlimitedStorage"
]
```

The max size for chrome sync storage is:

- 102,400 bytes total
- 8,192 bytes per item
- 512 items max
- 1,800 write operations per hour
- 120 operations per minutes

([source](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#properties))