# how to remove the chrome.storage.local

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

Im not getting how remove `chrome.storage.local` values in javascript?

i use like this but the storage value is not removing from the store:`chrome.storage.local.remove(result.MyFile.Base64File);`

Please check the below code, here I'm using **chrome.storage.local.set** to set

```
var obj = { DocName: "name", Base64File: "Base64string" };
                chrome.storage.local.set({ 'MyFile': obj });
```

and chrome.storage.local.get to retrive the values

```
   chrome.storage.local.get('MyFile', function (result) {
  var PdfBase64 = result.MyFile.Base64File;
   var DocumentName = result.MyFile.DocName;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note: You can not remove values, you can remove indexes with specific names what causes that they gets removed WITH there values.**

Tbh I could not run the code but I'm pretty sure something like this should work. But I really recommend you to avoid chrome.storage because it's some kind of "dumb" `:)`

So please have a look at this code:

```js
function clearItem(symbol) {
  var remove = [];

  chrome.storage.sync.get(function(Items) {
    $.each(Items, function(index, value) {
      if (index == "symbol") remove.push(index);
    });

    chrome.storage.sync.remove(remove, function(Items) {
      chrome.storage.sync.get(function(Items) {
        $.each(Items, function(index, value) {
          console.log("removed: " + index);
        });
      });
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: what is the difference between **chrome.storage.sync.get** and **chrome.storage.local.get**

Comment: @Mahendra sync and get are just two different Memorys- have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22636771/chrome-storage-sync-vs-chrome-storage-local :)

Comment: **chrome.storage.sync.remove**   it's working now thank you @jonas